# "Recursively" expressing continuous-time trajectories

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, dynamical-systems, recursion, transfinite-recursion

I am interested in functions of time I call "trajectories" $h$, each in an arbitrary codomain $D$. $D$ is a set.

- I wish to express that these trajectories are determined by an initial condition $h_0$ and an evolution/determining function $f$. (almost-)Like a dynamical system. $f$ can take any required form/signature, even complicated. And $f$ is supposed to be *given*.
- I also wish to express that the universe hosting these trajectories, represented by $f$, is gifted with a *memory* so any value taken by $h$ depends on *all* past values taken by $h$, and not on future values.

---

If time were **discrete**, I would express it this way:

\begin{equation}
\newcommand{\funmap}[4]{{%
        \left\{%
            \begin{array}{ccl}
            #1 & \to     & \ #2 \\
            #3 & \mapsto & \ #4
            \end{array}
        \right.
    }}
    h : \funmap{\mathbb{N}}{D}{n}{h(n)}
\end{equation}
then
\begin{align}
h(0) &= h_0\\
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*},\ h(n) &= f\left(h_{\big|[0,n[}\right) \text{ or } f\left(h_0, ..., h_{n-1}\right) \text{ ..}
\end{align}
.. depending on how we define $f$. Anyway, I repeat I'm mostly interested in expriming that:

---

**1.** given $f$ and $h_0$, $h$ is (constructively) completely determined (exists + is unique + we can compute it).
**2.** any value of $h$ depends on all its past values.

---

In **continuous** time however, I spontaneously try to express **2.** this way:

\begin{equation}
h : \funmap{\mathbb{R^+}}{D}{t}{h(t)}
\end{equation}

then
\begin{align}
h(0) &= h_0\\
\forall t \in \mathbb{R}^{+*},\ h(t) &= f\left(h_{\big|[0,t[}\right)
\end{align}

.. but I'm not sure that it makes **1.** hold. Is **1.** true then?
If not, how to express both **1.** and **2.** in continuous time?

---

I am aware that this sounds like a recursive definition over $\mathbb{R}^+$, which I think is impossible.. unless we accept the [axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) and make it a [transfinite recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) by forcing $\mathbb{R}^+$ to be [well-ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem)? Which is not [constructive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_analysis)..

Is there a better way to write this?

---

Tracks I could think of:

- discretizing $\mathbb{R}^+$, defining $h$ recursively on small bits.. then limit-reducing the size of the bits to zero. But I am afraid that everything would collapse at the limit resulting in $h$ being undefined.. would it be the case?
- generalizing the concept of "derivative" and "local variation" to any arbitrary set $D$. Then expressing **1.** and **2.** like a generalized version of an ODE. I like this option best, and I am aware that it necessitate some kind of *continuity* in $h$ that cannot be defined for any codomain $D$. But I have a couple of hypotheses we could make us of for this track:

---

Here are two interesting hypothese on $h$, that may help us:

- if $D$ topological, then $h$ is **piecewise-continuous**, and every piece interval has **positive lenght**.
- if not, then $h$ is **piecewise-constant**, and every piece interval has **positive length** as well.

---

Am I looking for something impossible to express?
Can I exploit these hypotheses in a useful way to express **1.** and **2.**?

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? Does it really change with time?

Comment: @JohnB The domain of $f$ is.. whatever makes it *not change with time*. Finding a way to express **1.** and **2.** will actually determine the domain of $f$. Put it another way: I don't know the domain of $f$, I just know that $f$ has to be fixed and "statically" determine the whole $h$. So the domain of $f$ is part of the answer. Does it make sense?

Comment: It cannot be say $h_0, ..., h_{n-1})$ as you write. The domain of a function cannot change as we wish. But you complicate it then a bit too much: look for *dynamical systems associated with autonomous differential equations*, which should be in line with what you want.

Comment: @JohnB The domain is not "changing" with $f\left(h_0, \dots, h_{n-1}\right)$, the signature is $f: D^{\mathbb{N}} = \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}{D^i} \rightarrow D$, which is *fixed*. (associate to each "past" $\mapsto$ one "present value") Is that not possible? :(  [EDIT:] Oh, maybe I should've written $f\left(\left(h_0, \dots, h_{n-1}\right)\right)$?

Comment: OK, a nonstandard view for dynamics, but now I understand what you mean (you do write "Like a dynamical system" but it is something else then). Thanks.

Comment: On your question: let me suggest the closest to the canonical way in dynamics. For simplicity let's assume here that $h$ is differentiable. Try to find $F$ such that $h'(t)=F(h(t))$. Then there exist (canonical) maps $\phi_t$ such that $\phi_t\circ\phi_s=\phi_{t+s}$ and $h(t)=\phi_t(h_0)$. Perhaps you can write this in the way that you want.

Comment: @JohnB Hm. And would $\phi_{t+s}$ be the expression of "depend on past values" then? I have a sudden doubt. For *any* given trajectory $h: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow D$, you may (circularily) define $f$ so that $f(h_{\big|[0,\ t[}) = h(t)$. So, in this view the property **1.** seems always true. Yet it would be not constructive. How to (=can we) characterize trajectories $h$ which are actually *built forward* from "another" function $f$? Like a function not defined from themselves?

Comment: That is already your problem. In dynamics we care zero whether it is "constructive" or not.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up with. I'll accept my own answer once someone makes me confident it's valid.

First, property "**2.**: $h$ depends on its past values" is a dumb property since it is *always* verified. *I.e.* for any given $h$, one may build the function $f$ so that $h(t) = f\left(h_{\big|[0,\ t[}\right)$.

However, we may approximate $h$ by a sequence $u$ for an arbitrarily accurate precision $\varepsilon$, then state than "$f$ determines $h$ from its past" if and only if the series it determines **is** the approximation of $h$ for all $\varepsilon$.

---

For any precison $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}^{+*}$, let ${}^\varepsilon h$ be the sequence approximating $h$ in the sense that:

\begin{equation}
\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\quad {}^\varepsilon h_n = h(n\varepsilon)
\end{equation}

Now, let's consider $F:\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\mathbb{R}^{+*} &\to& \mathcal{F}\!\left(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}D^i\to D\right)\\
\varepsilon &\mapsto& F(\varepsilon) = f_\varepsilon
\end{array}\right.$

Then, once given $h_0 = h(0) \in D$, any $F(\varepsilon)$ defines a sequence $f_\varepsilon\times h_0 = (u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by recursion with:

\begin{align}
u_0 &= h_0\\
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*,\ u_n &= f_\varepsilon(u_0,\ \dots,\ u_{n-1})\\
\end{align}

So I can finally state than

\begin{equation}
«\ F \text{ determines } h \text{ from its past } » \iff \forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{+*},\ f_\varepsilon\times h_0 = {}^\varepsilon h
\end{equation}

---

This way, I do have:

**1.** Given $f_\varepsilon$ and $h_0$, ${}^\varepsilon h$ is entirely defined. So given "$F$ determining $h$ from its past", I can approximate $h$ with arbitrary precision.

**2.** Any "present" approximation ${}^\varepsilon h_n$ is constructed from its "past" ${}^\varepsilon h_n = f_\varepsilon({}^\varepsilon h_0,\ \dots,\ {}^\varepsilon h_{n-1})$.

Comment: Mh, what's wrong?